# How is the training set called when using a validation set?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, terminology

The question might be not so clear. However, my confusion comes from the following approach: Suppose I use training, testing and validation sets. First, I split my data into training and testing. To tune my parameters (e.g., for pruning a classification tree), I then split my training set into validation and XX. I cannot use the term training set again but how is this set (training-valiation) called?

Answer (score 4):

I agree that the employed terminology is not so great. Here is one way to make it unambiguous, which is used in the [AMI Corpus documentation](http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/ami/corpus/datasets.shtml):

First, you can split the data into *seen* and *unseen* data. You then split your seen data into *validation* set and *training* set. The *unseen* test is also called *test* set. The *validation* set is also called *development* set, or *hold-out* data.

Comment: There is even more ambiguity because in my field validation would correspond to the test set rather than the development set (or even to data obtained by a validation study, not by splitting some data set). Not knowing the AMI definitions, I've used "optimization set" or "optimization test set" for the inner "validation set".

Comment: @cbeleites Interesting. What is your field? is development set synonymous with validation set as well?

Comment: I'm analytical chemist / chemometrician. I've not met the term "development set" before. At some point I decided always to spell out which set I refer to by which term.

Comment: @cbeleites When even the terms to split the data are ambiguous, one may wonder if stats/ML terminology doesn't need some serious cleaning :/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't split your training set, because initially you split your data to training set, cross-validation set and test set. Usually corresponding ratios are 60% + 20% + 20%

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I see your point. However, since I'd like to run a cross-validation to get more robust results, I guess I cannot just split it in the beginning. Of course, if I would just to a one-time random split, your solution would clearly be correct. At least this is how I think about it. But I see, I was not clear about this!